# Correct apporach to call a function in javascript/jquery using function's name

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am having a function like this in one of the script file,

```
function ex(data){
//do something
}
```

I want to call this function from another script file with parameters.
What should be the correct approach? I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) which is having many solutions, I tried them all but all are working in mozilla only.

Also I am new to javascript/jquery so please pardon my silly mistakes if any.

Comment: You need to include the `script file` where the above `function` exists, before the `script file` where you are calling this `function`

Comment: Make sure your `ex` function is under global scope..

Comment: I assume `window.ex()` throws a TypeError? Use some developer tools to debug.

Comment: Why you give a -1 to this question? Really I don't understand. He's a novice javascript programmer and he's using stack overflow to understand and learn new things.

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like that:

first.js

```
function ex(number) {
    alert(number);
}
```

second.js

```
function otherFunction() {
     ex("two");
}
```

Now you should include these two js files in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    otherFunction( );
</script>
```